# How do I add a super user same as 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: connection, admin, super

I want to add a super user that has the same privileges as 'root'@'localhost' because I want to create a host that is '%' accessible that my local machine will serve as a remote database server.

P.S. I am using xampp > phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 90;
```

Refer the **[docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)** here.

Comment: I actually my real problem is I cannot access phpmyadmin from my account at host '%'

Comment: How? Because I have created a user with host as "%'

Comment: Login to the MySQL console using your root password and then create a new user there.